# Создать таблицу на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Я хочу использовать значения 2 полей ввода и сделать таблицу. `<tr>` должны быть равны значению, заданному в `#inp1`, а `<td>` - `#inp2`.

```js
$("#create").click(function() {
  var x = $("#inp1").val();
  var y = $("#inp2").val();

  $("#tab").remove();
  
  var table = $("<table id = 'tab'></div>");

  table.appendTo("body");
})
```

```html
<input id="inp1" type="" name="">
<input id="inp2" type="" name="">
<button id="create">CREATE</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ранее вы совершенно нормально писали по-русски, почему сейчас вдруг перешли на английский в вопросе и комментариях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#create', function() {

  $("#tab").remove()

  var table = $('<table id="tab"/>')
  var columnsCount = $('#inp1').val()
  var rowsCount = $('#inp2').val()

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr/>')

    for (var j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++) {
      var cell = $('<td/>')

      cell.html('ячейка')
      row.append(cell)
    }

    table.append(row)
  }

  table.appendTo('body')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inp1" type="number" value="3" placeholder="Количество колонок" />
<input id="inp2" type="number" value="4" placeholder="Количество строк" />
<button id="create" type="button">CREATE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
let table           = document.createElement("table"),
    caption         = document.createElement("caption"),
    inputs          = document.querySelectorAll(".table");


table.setAttribute("border", "1");
caption.innerHTML = "TABLE";

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    let     tr            = document.createElement("tr");
    let     index         = document.createElement("td");
    let     value         = document.createElement("td");

    index.innerHTML = 'Input #' + (i+1);
    tr.appendChild(index);

    value.innerHTML = inputs[i].value;
    tr.appendChild(value);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(caption);
document.body.appendChild(table);
});
```

Вы можете иметь много входов. Просто добавьте один новый в HTML, и скрипт прочитает их все.
Это лучше, чем читать только 2 входа.

Comment: Thanks, dude, but I need it with Jquery